How to fix `NX Could not load plugin @nx/jest/plugin`?
I have an advanced angular application v18.x where I use NX (Monorepo).
I did upgrade eslint from v8.x to v9.6.0. After that I removed node_modules, package-lock.json, cleaned the cache and ran: npm install --force. All fine.
When I try to run/start the app I keep facing the following error:

NX   Could not load plugin @nx/jest/plugin

The log in: .nx/workspace-data/d/daemon.log says:

[NX Daemon Server] - 2024-07-24T11:12:05.918Z - [REQUEST]: Responding to the client with an error. Error when preparing serialized project graph. Could not load plugin @nx/jest/plugin LoadPluginError: Could not load plugin @nx/jest/plugin
at loadNxPluginAsync (/Users/myName/FolderX/myapp/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/plugins/loader.js:208:15)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async load (/Users/myName/FolderX/myapp/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/plugins/isolation/plugin-worker.js:26:30)
at async consumeMessage (/Users/myName/FolderX/myapp/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/plugins/isolation/messaging.js:37:26)

I have been searching and debugging, but still cannot localize the exact cause. Any hint and/or idea how to fix this issue?

Have you run pnpm i or yarn etc?
I also forgot to do it and got the same error as with you

Make sure that all @nx/* packages and the nx package are using the same version. Verify this in all package.json files that have devDependencies and/or dependencies settings, not only the package.json file in the root of the workspace.
